# Using faster than light signals to synchronize clocks

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, faster-than-light

> What would happen if one could communicate by non-luminous signals whose velocity of propagation differed from that of light? If, after having adjusted the watches by the optical procedure, we wished to verify the adjustment by the aid of these new signals, **we should observe discrepancies which would render evident the common translation of the two stations**. And are such signals inconceivable, if we admit with Laplace that universal gravitation is transmitted a million times more rapidly than light? [Poincare, 1904 address]

So to eliminate possibility of measurements by faster than light signals, Poincare assumed that the gravity should not propagate at faster than light speed. He limited it to the speed of light.

I think that Poincare is saying that if the clocks have been synchronized by light signals then using any faster-than-light signal would make it obvious that an inertial frame is moving. Assuming my interpretation is correct, why would it make it clear that inertial frame of reference is moving or why one "should observe discrepancies" if faster-than-light signals are used to synchronize the clocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Assuming my interpretation is correct, why would it make it clear that inertial frame of reference is moving or why one "should observe discrepancies" if faster-than-light signals are used to synchronize the clocks?

Your interpretation is correct, but in this case Poincare is wrong. Remember, if the date is correct then this address was given prior to Einstein’s paper On The Electrodynamics Of Moving Bodies. He would have been discussing Lorentz Aether Theory.

If a signal propagated at v>c with respect to the Lotentz aether then it would be possible to detect the velocity of the aether using that signal. To make visualization easier let’s assume that the signal travels instantaneously with respect to the aether (similar conclusions follow for other propagation velocities).

In that case, if you are at rest with respect to the aether and you synchronize your clocks optically and then emit this superluminal signal from midway between the synchronized clocks the signal will be received at the same time according to the optically synchronized clocks. On the other hand, if your clocks are optically synchronized while moving with respect to the aether then the clocks will disagree about the time that the superluminal signal is received due to the relativity of simultaneity for local time in Lorentz’s theory.

Thus far Poincare is correct. A superluminal signal which traveled at a defined velocity with respect to the aether would violate the principle of relativity and allow the measurement of “absolute” velocity.

However, where Poincare is incorrect is in thinking that a superluminal signal would necessarily travel at a fixed velocity with respect to the aether. Suppose, instead, that the superluminal signal travels at a fixed velocity with respect to the emitter. In that case, then the signals received at the optically synchronized clocks would be received simultaneously regardless of the velocity of the pair of clocks.

Note, in this case, it is possible to show that a signal which travels at a fixed v>c with respect to the emitter can be used to violate causality (see https://pages.uoregon.edu/imamura/FPS/images/p263_1 ) whereas a signal which travels at a fixed v>c with respect to the aether cannot. Thus out of relativity, causality, and superluminal signals it is only possible to have two (see http://www.physicsmatt.com/blog/2016/8/25/why-ftl-implies-time-travel ). Most scientists believe that relativity and causality are correct so superluminal signals are impossible.

Comment: Your answer is really good but I would like to clarify some important points.

_"If a signal propagated at v>c with respect to the Lotentz aether then it would be possible to detect the velocity of the aether using that signal.... A superluminal signal which traveled at a defined velocity with respect to the aether would violate the principle of relativity and allow the measurement of “absolute” velocity."_ I believe you assume that such a superluminal signal would use aether as a medium. In MM experiment they also tried to detect the velocity of aether or absolute velocity **Cont'd**

Comment: but they couldn't detect any aether wind. The reason was length contraction in one of the arms. If the clocks have been synced using a superliminal signal then optical signal would reveal the motion of an inertial frame of reference which also breaks the principle of relativity. Please correct me if I'm wrong. But there is another problem, when the speed of anything reaches c, the time stops so for a superliminal signal the time would always run negative, imaginary, or what. At speed of c, the length also becomes zero so what would be the length for a superluminal signal, less than **Cont'd**

Comment: zero? I'd really appreciate if you could comment on it

_"Suppose, instead, that it travels at a fixed velocity with respect to the emitter."_ Doesn't light travel at a fixed velocity with respect to the everything include the source?

_"Note, in this case, it is possible to show that a signal which travels at a fixed v>c with respect to the emitter can be used to violate causality whereas a signal which travels at a fixed v>c with respect to the aether cannot."_ Could you please elaborate a little?

Comment: “when the speed of anything reaches c, the time stops so for a superliminal signal the time would always run negative, imaginary, or what” Proper time is only defined for timelike paths, so for a signal moving at c or at v>c proper time is undefined. I would not say that time stops or is negative or imaginary, just that it is undefined in those cases. Similarly for proper length

Comment: “Doesn't light travel at a fixed velocity with respect to the everything include the source?” Yes, I was talking about the superluminal signal, not light. I will edit my answer to clarify.

Comment: @Dale, isn't there another possible interpretation of what occurs under hypothetical FTL conditions, which is that you simply get a "luminal boom" by analogy with a sonic boom, where you hear the object arrive before hearing it leave it's origin, whereas the object itself which causes the boom simply proceeds forwards as normal?

Comment: @Steve That is an additional effect that also happens, not an alternative interpretation. The “luminal boom” is called Cherenkov radiation and is easily observed in transparent media. My comments above are talking about the superluminal object itself, not the Cherenkov radiation.

Comment: @Dale, the crucial point I was making was also about the superluminal object itself. You say time would run negative for it. I say *time* will continue forward just like for the supersonic object - all that will happen is that, if it attempts to assay it's environment using luminal methods, events will appear to occur in reverse order (but time will proceed forward in all places).

Comment: @Steve then you do not understand the issue. I recommend asking a separate question where it can be answered fully (more likely it has already been asked). Comments are for improving the answer, not for discussion and not for additional questions.

Comment: @Dale, the comment improves your answer by presenting an apparent oversight on your part.

Comment: @Steve it is not an oversight. You misunderstand the reason for the violation of causality. I am not going to incorporate this misunderstanding into the answer. It would not be an improvement

Comment: @Dale, under the assumption of FTL travel, I'd be surprised if your definition of causality remained standing, because it will be founded upon there being no FTL travel which is the very constraint which is being removed for the purpose of posing the question (which you've chosen to answer). Whether you choose to take any action is a decision I leave to you. Comments are for improving answers, not for seeking the approval of answerers.

Comment: @Steve the causality issue is well described in the literature. It isn’t my definition. I choose not to take any action to bring my answer in conflict with the scientific literature

Comment: @Dale _"so for a signal moving at c or at v>c proper time is undefined. I would not say that time stops or is negative or imaginary, just that it is undefined in those cases. "_ But it's said that a photon could get, say, from sun to earth in zero time. Perhaps, it's just pop science way of explaining things in layman terms.

Comment: @Dale I'm sorry to repeat it. It might be that it requires a separate detailed answer and you decided not to reply to it, if that's the case then it's fine. _"Note, in this case, it is possible to show that a signal which travels at a fixed v>c with respect to the emitter can be used to violate causality whereas a signal which travels at a fixed v>c with respect to the aether cannot."_

Comment: @PG1995 “Perhaps, it's just pop science way of explaining things in layman terms”. Yes, that is correct. It is something that I have never seen in the peer reviewed literature. It seems to be a bit of “poetic license” used primarily to sell pop-science media. None of the pop-science sources I have read ever follow it up with a discussion about affine parameters, which is the standard quantity used in the scientific literature instead of proper time for a flash of light.

Comment: I will add to that part of the answer (causality and FTL) with a good reference, but it will have to wait until this evening

Comment: @Dale I just wanted to remind you. I understand that you might be busy but please try to help me with a simple answer when you get a chance. I was confused about the following: "_Note, in this case, it is possible to show that a signal which travels at a fixed v>c with respect to the emitter can be used to violate causality whereas a signal which travels at a fixed v>c with respect to the aether cannot._"

Comment: @PG1995 so sorry about that. I completely got distracted and forgot. I have added two links, one is to one of the famous scientific papers on the topic and the other is to a blog which is less technical and hopefully easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Note that although a super-luminal method would establish an objectively preferred frame for light - and light would become subject to the same interpretation as sound (which exhibits all the same properties as relativity, if the clocks themselves are all implemented through the exchange of sound signals) - the question could still remain as to whether this super-luminal method itself had any preferred frame, and therefore it would not intrinsically defeat those who argue that no such frame exists at the final frontier (although it would deal them a blow to credibility, and people would ask why an exceptionalist interpretation is always being applied to the fastest known method at any time).

If there is to be any *experimental* resolution of the question, then anyone postulating the existence of a preferred frame, must propose some technique by which it can be detected from within, rather than detected from outside by a hypothetical faster or instantaneous means of transmission.